# Select multiple rows with the same value(s)

Tags: sql, rows

I have a table, sort of like this:

```
ID  |  Chromosome | Locus | Symbol | Dominance |
===============================================
1   |      10     |   2   |   A    |   Full    |
2   |      10     |   2   |   a    |   Rec.    |
3   |      10     |   3   |   B    |   Full    |
4   |      10     |   3   |   b    |   Rec.    |
```

I'd like to select all rows with the same locus and chromosome.  For example, rows 3 and 4.  There may be more than 2 at a time and they may not be in order.

I tried this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Genes
GROUP BY Locus
HAVING Locus='3' AND Chromosome='10'
```

But it always returns row 3, never row 4, even when repeated.  I think I'm missing something obvious and simple, but I'm at a loss.

Can someone help?

Comment: rows 1 and 2 also have the same locus and chromosome, what do you actually want as a result of your query?

Comment: Lamak--I want to select a certain locus and chromosome and get all the rows that match.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You need to understand that when you include `GROUP BY` in your query you are telling SQL to combine rows.  you will get one row per unique `Locus` value.  The `Having` then filters those groups.  Usually you specify an aggergate function in the select list like:

```
--show how many of each Locus there is
SELECT COUNT(*),Locus FROM Genes GROUP BY Locus

--only show the groups that have more than one row in them
SELECT COUNT(*),Locus FROM Genes GROUP BY Locus HAVING COUNT(*)>1

--to just display all the rows for your condition, don't use GROUP BY or HAVING
SELECT * FROM Genes WHERE Locus = '3' AND Chromosome = '10'
```

Comment: So, yep the problem was with my php code, not my sql code. *blush*  Went back to my original syntax of `SELECT * FROM Genes WHERE Locus = '3' AND Chromosome = '10'` as so many suggested, fixed my php code, and all's right with the world!  Knew it was something simple and obvious that I was missing!  Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 12):

*Assuming that you want all rows for which there is another row with the exact same `Chromosome` and `Locus`:*

You can achieve this by joining the table to itself, but only returning the columns from one "side" of the join.

The trick is to set the join condition to "the same locus and chromosome":

```
select left.*
from Genes left
inner join Genes right
on left.Locus = right.Locus and 
  left.Chromosome = right.Chromosome and left.ID != right.ID
```

You can also easily extend this by adding a filter in a `where`-clause.

Comment: @Matt Fenwick Thanks so much! This helped out a lot.

Comment: FWIW this worked fine for me after I changed "left" to "l" and "right" to "r" -- maybe "left" is a reserved keyword in MariaDB where I'm using it, or something.

Comment: Though using "left" or "right" doesn't work because they're reserved keywords, the use of inner joins here is the best solution. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `GROUP BY` - if you group results by Locus, you only get one result per locus.

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM Genes WHERE Locus = '3' AND Chromosome = '10';
```

If you prefer using `HAVING` syntax, then `GROUP BY id` or something that is not repeating in the result set.

Comment: That's actually the original syntax I used.  It and `GROUP BY id` both give the same result.

Answer (score 1):

This may work for you:

```
select t1.*
from table t1
join (select t2.Chromosome, t2.Locus
    from table2
    group by t2.Chromosome, t2.Locus
    having count(*) > 1) u on u.Chromosome = t1.Chromosome and u.Locus = t1.Locus
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is via an `exists` clause:

```
select * from genes g
where exists
(select null from genes g1
 where g.locus = g1.locus and g.chromosome = g1.chromosome and g.id <> g1.id)
```

Alternatively, in MySQL you can get a summary of all matching ids with a single table access, using `group_concat`:

```
select group_concat(id) matching_ids, chromosome, locus 
from genes
group by chromosome, locus
having count(*) > 1
```