# Finding Records using Rails without a Match (Fault without Fault Cleared)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I'm attempting to write a site in Rails where a user in a manufacturing plant can see what devices are failing. The program storing the alarm data stores one entry when a device faults, and then stores another entry when the device gets fixed. The entries are linked only by having the same value in the `EventAssociationID` column. How might I write a named scope in Rails to check which faults have been fixed and which ones haven't?

Comment: can't this be done with an Outer Join on the EventAssociationID if these events are stored in different tables. Otherwise you might look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232986/sql-select-multiple-rows-with-same-values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to do it in a named scope, however, I was able to define a method for the model that solved the problem:

```
def inAlarm
  return ConditionEvent.count(:all, :conditions => ['EventAssociationID = ?', self.EventAssociationID]) == 1
end
```