# Oracle SQL - Comparing Rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a problem I'm working on with Oracle SQL that goes something like this.

TABLE

```
 PurchaseID    CustID      Location  
----1------------1-----------A  
----2------------1-----------A    
----3------------2-----------A  
----4------------2-----------B  
----5------------2-----------A  
----6------------3-----------B  
----7------------3-----------B
```

I'm interested in querying the Table to return all instances where the same customer makes a purchase in different locations. So, for the table above, I would want:

OUTPUT

```
PurchaseID    CustID      Location  
----3------------2-----------A  
----4------------2-----------B  
----5------------2-----------A
```

Any ideas on how to accomplish this? I haven't been able to think of how to do it, and most of my ideas seem like they would be pretty clunky. The database I'm using has 1MM+ records, so I don't want it to run too slowly.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How many different locations, how many different customers?

Comment: The question is a simplified version of what I'm really doing at work, but in the real database there are 5 different values for the variable I'm calling Location here (also some nulls), and there are about 500,000 different "customers."

Comment: Then it might be best in performance terms to construct all five sets for different locations and intersect them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable T
WHERE CustId IN (SELECT CustId
                 FROM YourTable
                 GROUP BY CustId
                 HAVING MIN(Location) <> MAX(Location))
```

Comment: That was fast! Thanks! What is that Min(Location) <> MAX(Location) doing that is making it work?

Comment: @user1895076 It is for making sure that it has at least 2 different locations. You could also use `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Location)>1`

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Min would be the minimum number of locations by CustID? Also, I was going to tackle this next, maybe you can help.

I have a fourth column with a purchase date. The next step was I wanted to reduce the OUTPUT table above down to just those instances where there were purchases made in different locations within 2 years of each other. It should return all instances where one customer made at least two purchases in different locations within 2 years of each other.

Comment: @user1895076 No, in this case the `MIN(Location)` is the minimum value of `Location` (in your example, 'A'). And, for your next question, it really is a different question as the one you have now

Comment: @user1895076 Your edit to include the 2 year date requirement should be posted to a new question. You have now altered this one to be totally different from your original post.  Please ask a new question with the updated requirements.

Comment: Deleted the edit. Will post as a new question if I can't find the answer.

Comment: I think this will be the most efficient with an index on `(CustId, Location)`

Comment: @ypercube I think that Andriy's answer will be more efficient, not sure though

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to use something similar to the following:

```
select purchaseid, custid, location
from yourtable
where custid in (select custid
                  from yourtable
                  group by custid
                  having count(distinct location) >1);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/559e9/2).

The subquery in the WHERE clause is returning all `custids` that have a total number of distinct locations that are greater than 1.

Answer (score 6):

In English:

> Select a row if another row exists with the same customer and a different location.

In SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM atable t
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM atable
  WHERE CustID = t.CustID
    AND Location <> t.Location
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach using a sub-query

```
SELECT T1.PurchaseID
        ,T1.CustID
        ,T1.Location
FROM    YourTable T1
INNER JOIN
        (SELECT T2.CustID
                ,COUNT (DISTINCT T2.Location )
        FROM    YourTable T1
        GROUP BY
                T2.CustID
        HAVING  COUNT (DISTINCT T2.Location )>1
        ) SQ
ON      SQ.CustID = T1.CustID
```

Answer (score 0):

This should only require one full table scan.

```
create table test (PurchaseID number, CustID number, Location varchar2(1));
insert into test values (1,1,'A');
insert into test values (2,1,'A');
insert into test values (3,2,'A');
insert into test values (4,2,'B');
insert into test values (5,2,'A');
insert into test values (6,3,'B');
insert into test values (7,3,'A');

with repeatCustDiffLocations as (
    select PurchaseID, custid, location, dense_rank () over (partition by custid order by location) r
    from test)
select b.*
from repeatCustDiffLocations a, repeatCustDiffLocations b
where a.r > 1
and a.custid = b.custid;
```

Answer (score 0):

This makes most sense to me as I was trying to return the rows with the same values throughout the table, specifically for two columns as shown [in this stackoverflow answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232986/select-multiple-rows-with-the-same-values/9233029#9233029)

The answer to your problem in this format is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.*
FROM TEST a
INNER JOIN TEST b
ON a.CUSTOMERID = b.CUSTOMERID AND
a.LOCATION <> b.LOCATION;
```

However, the solution to a problem such as mine with two columns having matching values in multiple rows (2 in this instance, would yield no results because all PurchaseID's are unique):

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.*
FROM TEST a
INNER JOIN TEST b
ON a.CUSTOMERID = b.CUSTOMERID AND
a.PURCHASEID = b.PURCHASEID AND
a.LOCATION <> b.LOCATION;
```

Although, this wouldn't return the correct results based on the what needs to be queried, it shows that the query logic works

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.*
FROM TEST a
INNER JOIN TEST b
ON a.CUSTOMERID = b.CUSTOMERID AND
a.PURCHASEID <> b.PURCHASEID AND
a.LOCATION = b.LOCATION;
```

If anyone wants to try in Oracle here is the table and values to insert:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (
PurchaseID integer,
CustomerID integer,
Location varchar(1));

INSERT ALL
  INTO TEST VALUES (1, 1, 'A')
  INTO TEST VALUES (2, 1, 'A')
  INTO TEST VALUES (3, 2, 'A')
  INTO TEST VALUES (4, 2, 'B')
  INTO TEST VALUES (5, 2, 'A')
  INTO TEST VALUES (6, 3, 'B')
  INTO TEST VALUES (7, 3, 'B')
SELECT * FROM DUAL;
```