# Get only the rows with duplicated values for a field in Grails

Tags: grails

I know we can get distinct records from a table using

```
projections {
   distinct "propertyName"
}
```

for createCriteria. But how can I get only those rows for which another row may have the same value for some specified column? For instance, if I have a Vehicle domain with 2 instances with type car, 3 instances with type motorbike, and 1 with type bicycle, I only want to get the list with entries for the cars and motorbikes.

Basically, I want to implement something like [Select multiple rows with the same value(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232986/select-multiple-rows-with-the-same-values)

I was able to get the value using the sql solution mentioned in the page like

```
SELECT Locus FROM Genes GROUP BY Locus HAVING count(*)>1;
```

However, I'm not sure how we can implement this using grails createCriteria.

Comment: hql should be able to do this too

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a personal preference than a direct answer to your question but, I like to use direct/native sql for anything that is outside of the basics of criteria queries. This is because complex criteria queries can be hard to debug and difficult for others to understand (IMO).

Direct sql also allows me to know exactly what is happening and I can ensure that it's using the most efficient sql.

```
    import groovy.sql.Sql 

   ...

    def query = " SELECT Locus FROM Genes GROUP BY Locus HAVING count(*)>1; "
    def sql = new Sql(dataSource)
    def results = sql.rows(query)
   //do stuff with results
```